# PHP // White screen of death with all errors reporting on

Tags: php, codeigniter, debugging, error-handling, xampp

With everything i have tried regarding showing errors, i am still getting white screen of death.

Please note that i am using XAMPP to develop the website. 
Is there anything else i could do? Take a look also at my code, because i have no idea if it is working.

The code is the following:

```
<?php

error_reporting(-1);  // Have PHP complain about absolutely everything 
$conf['error_level'] = 2;  // Show all messages on your screen, 2 = ERROR_REPORTING_DISPLAY_ALL.
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);  // These lines just give you content on WSOD pages.
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);

require("dbconn.php");
$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

    $Username   =   $_POST['username']; #Username
    $Password   =   $_POST['password']; #Password

function InsrtUser()
{
    global $Username,$Password;
    #Egxwrish stoixeiwn
    $hashed_pass = PASSWORD_HASH($Password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    $query = "INSERT INTO users (username,password) VALUES (:username, :password)";
    $data = $mysqli->prepare($query);
    $data->execute(array(':username'=>$Username, ':password'=>$hashed_pass));
    if($data->rowCount() > 0)
    {
        return "YOUR REGISTRATION IS COMPLETED...";
    }
}

function Register()
{
    global $Username,$Password;
    if(!empty($Username))   //checking the 'username' name which is from register.html, if is it empty or have some text
        {
                $query = ("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username");
                $query = $mysqli->prepare($query);
                $query->execute(array(':username'=>$Username));
                if($query->rowCount() == 0)
            {
                $msg = InsrtUser();
                echo $msg;
            }
            else {
                echo "SORRY...YOU ARE ALREADY registerED USER...!";
                die();
            }

        }
}

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    //User registration
    Register();
    echo "Your account has been created successfully. \\n Thank you for joined us!";
    $msgSuccess = "Your account has been created successfully. \\n Thank you for joined us!";
        echo 
            "<script>
            alert('$msgSuccess');
            window.location.href='../index.php';
            </script>";

}
?>
```

Comment: Use `error_reporting(E_ALL)` instead of `error_reporting(-1)`. Also - check your error log file. Anything interesting there?

Comment: Maybe it is not death screen but `$_POST['submit']` is not set?

Comment: @uri2x `E_ALL` is equivalent to `-1` and shows all errors. PHP Manual: `Passing in the value -1 will show every possible error, even when new levels and constants are added in future PHP versions. The E_ALL constant also behaves this way as of PHP 5.4. `

Comment: @CharlotteDunois Fair enough. I would still prefer `E_ALL` for code readability tho.

Comment: Thank you guys, I also tried with E_ALL. The problem found by @chris85.  
It was regarding to $_POST['submit'].

Comment: @chris85 post your answer so it can be officially accepted. You deserve the credit.

Comment: Okay, answer posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This actually isn't a death screen scenario you are running into. You're only outputting content if `$_POST['submit']` is set. If that is not set nothing is outputted so a white screen (no-content) is the expected value, which is what you get.

I presume the issue is that your submit button didn't have the name attribute `submit`.

In the future adding an else will also help you debug these..

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    //User registration
    Register();
    echo "Your account has been created successfully. \\n Thank you for joined us!";
    $msgSuccess = "Your account has been created successfully. \\n Thank you for joined us!";
        echo 
            "<script>
            alert('$msgSuccess');
            window.location.href='../index.php';
            </script>";

} else {
    echo 'The submit button is not set :(';
}
```